# How to make a C++ function that performs an in-place operation available to another R package using Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

Say I have an R package called "packA" that contains the following file "funcA.cpp":

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void funcA (arma::vec& x) {
  x += 1;
}
```

Calling this function from R yields the expected result of adding 1 to each element of the vector in-place:

```
> vec <- c(1, 2, 3)
> funcA(vec)
> vec
[1] 2 3 4
```

Now say I have a second package "packB" that wants to call the function "funcA". It contains the following file called "funcB.cpp":

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <packA.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void funcB() {
  arma::vec x = {1, 2, 3};

  Rcout << x << "\n";
  packA::funcA(x);
  Rcout << x << "\n";
}
```

Calling this function no longer yields the desired result, as it would appear that the vector x is no longer modified in-place:

```
> funcB()
   1.0000
   2.0000
   3.0000

   1.0000
   2.0000
   3.0000
```

Is there any way to preserve the in-place operations of C++ functions while still using Rcpp? Thanks in advance for any advice.

**Edit:**
I modified "funcB.cpp" according to Dirk Eddelbüttel's suggestion:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <packA.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void funcB(arma::vec& y) {
  packA::funcA(y);
}
```

Unfortunately, the result when calling the function from R was the same:

```
> vec <- c(1, 2, 3)
> funcB(vec)
> vec
[1] 1 2 3
```

**Edit 2:**
After some further experimentation I noticed that things start to break down as soon as `arma::vec& x` is in the footprint of `funcA`. Simply using a `NumericVector` works:

*"funcA.cpp"*

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void funcA (NumericVector& num_x) {
  num_x[2] = 10 + num_x[2];
}
```

```
> vec <- c(1, 2, 3)
> funcA(vec)
> vec
[1]  1  2 13
```

*"funcB.cpp"*

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <packA.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void funcB(NumericVector& num_y) {
  packA::funcA(num_y);
}
```

```
> vec <- c(1, 2, 3)
> funcB(vec)
> vec
[1]  1  2 13
```

Even using the advanced `arma::vec` constructor to create an Armadillo vector with shared memory works *as long as the input is a `NumericVector`*:

*"funcA.cpp"*

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void funcA (NumericVector& num_x) {
  arma::vec x_int = arma::vec(num_x.begin(), 3, false, false);
  x_int(2) = 10 + x_int(2);
}
```

```
> vec <- c(1, 2, 3)
> funcA(vec)
> vec
[1]  1  2 13

> vec <- c(1, 2, 3)
> funcB(vec)
> vec
[1]  1  2 13
```

Trying the same thing with an `arma::vec` no longer works.

*"funcA.cpp"*

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void funcA (arma::vec& x) {
  arma::vec x_int = arma::vec(x.begin(), 3, false, false);
  x(2) = 10 + x(2);
}
```

```
> vec <- c(1, 2, 3)
> funcA(vec)
> vec
[1]  1  2 13
```

*"funcB.cpp"*

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <packA.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void funcB(arma::vec& y) {
  packA::funcA(y);
}
```

```
> vec <- c(1, 2, 3)
> funcB(vec)
> vec
[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that is a different topic.   When you call `A`, you create an R vector.  That R vector is constructed with R memory, which R "own" and which we let Armadillo reuse.  In-place is possible there.

But when you run `B`, you construct an *Armadillo* vector not owned by R.  That is not "our" memory in R, and the content only ever comes back via a copy. And you loose the in-place mod. Make that function have an `arma::vec` signature, and pass an existing vector instead.

Comment: First off, thanks for taking the time to respond! I edited the question according to your suggestion. Unfortunately, the result when calling the function from R was the same. Additionally, my use case would actually require vectors created in C++ to be edited in place, as in the original example. Do you think this would still be possible, while still working with Rcpp?

Comment: There is no _fundamental reason_ why it shouldn't. All Rcpp does is help you with the underlying `SEXP .Call("somefun", SEXP a, SEXP b, ...)` calls.  And the `SEXP` are still _pointers_.  Yet it is possibly for you to 'break the the chain' along the way.

Comment: Would you have any pointers (pun slightly intended) as to where such a break in the chain is most likely to occur?

Comment: Start with the simplest case and change your interfaces to `SEXP sx` and instantiate to / convert back from an `arma::vec` as one does.  Maybe try the same with `Rcpp::NumericVector`.  At some point you will see a difference.  There may even be a bug somewhere, though these interfaces are fairly trusted and stable and have not changed in some time.

Comment: I played around with it a bit more and noticed that things seem to stop working as soon as `arma::vec&` is used. Both `SEXP` and `NumericVector` worked as expected (see my edit for the `NumericVector` case). Is there something I am still missing/not understanding?

Comment: Well the function signatures are all there for you to study, and if you think you found a reproducible "bug" feel free to report it. Maybe this is due to the `const` and `&` correctness changes for `arma::vec` from/to R.   I note that what you are chasing here is _not_ a promised feature.  We only say things about R interfaces to/from Armadillo.